# Not able to solve repository issue

Tags: android, repository

I added this to my app 
compile `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'`

> Error:(31, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1

```
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br>
<a href="openFile:G:/android projects/TechnFun/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br>
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

not able to solve the issue

Comment: do your other support library have version same as "21.0.0-rc1"?

Comment: other libraries 
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'

Comment: Try : com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1

as your other support libraries version.

Comment: All library version should be same, so use com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 and for other support libraries also.